# Django REST - POST request (auth_user + anotherTable)

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am working on implementing a POST request in Django REST where I am adding a new user. Since I'm using the integrated User model, I have an auth_user table and an additional profile table where I store some additional data (department, profile_photo, monthly_salary, tech_stack). When I add a new user, only first_name and last_name are added, and null values ​​are saved for the other fields.

Here is my code:

**SERIALIZER**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ('department', 'monthly_salary', 'tech_stack', 'profile_photo')

class AddUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')

        first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', '')
        last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', '')
        username = slugify(first_name + last_name)
    
        user = User.objects.create(username=username, **validated_data)
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user
```

**VIEW**

```
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class EmployeeAddView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {
        'first_name': request.data.get('first_name'), 
        'last_name': request.data.get('last_name'), 
        'profile': {
            'profile_photo': request.data.get('profile_photo'),
            'department': request.data.get('department'), 
            'monthly_salary': request.data.get('monthly_salary'), 
            'tech_stack': request.data.get('tech_stack')
        }
    }
    serializer = AddUserSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I send JSON (e.g.):

{
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"profile": {
"profile_photo":"http://localhost:3000/uploads/user/avatar/1/cd8.jpeg",
"department": "Development",
"monthly_salary": "2500.00",
"tech_stack": "Full stack"
}
},

I recieve:

{
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"profile": {
"department": null,
"monthly_salary": null,
"tech_stack": null,
"profile_photo": null
}
}

Does anyone know where could be the problem?
I connected Profile and auth_user, they are pretty fine (OneToOne Relationship).

Thank you in advance!